# Creating UUIDs in Elixir

Tags: elixir

What's a canonical way to generate UUIDs in Elixir? Should I necessarily use the library https://hex.pm/packages/uuid or is there a built-in library? I better have less dependencies and do more work than vise versa, therefore if I can generate in Elixir with an external dependency, it'll better go with it.

Comment: Why do you need to produce UUIDs? There are simpler built-in ways to generate unique keys/identifiers for things if you don't actually require true UUIDs.

Comment: @BenDamman, what are they?

Comment: `:rand.uniform()`, for example. `Integer.to_string(:rand.uniform(4294967296), 32) <> Integer.to_string(:rand.uniform(4294967296), 32)`
will give you a 64 bit random identifier in base64 (don't get more than 32 bits or so out of rand.uniform - so if you need the full 128 bits, do four calls and string them together)

Comment: (no clue why I can't edit my own comment, but here's a 128 bit version that should work well: `((:rand.uniform(4294967296) <<< 96) ||| (:rand.uniform(4294967296) <<< 64) ||| (:rand.uniform(4294967296) <<< 32) ||| (:rand.uniform(4294967296))) |> Integer.to_string(36)` - after a `use Bitwise`, of course)

Comment: @cdegroot, thx.

Comment: @cdegroot, where did 4294967296 come from?

Comment: That number is 2^32, so you get a number in that range (come to think of it, `:rand.uniform(n)` returns a number `1..n` so there should be a `-1` in there to make it `0..n-1`.

Comment: @BenDamman for example, `:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(10) |> Base.encode32()`

Comment: A random number isn't guaranteed only to generate unique values. Unless I'm missing something, this approach would eventually result in a collision.

Answer (score 37):

```
import Ecto

uuid = Ecto.UUID.generate
```

Comment: Not every Elixir project uses DB and Ecto mate.

Comment: You don't need to `import Ecto`, do you? `Ecto.UUID.generate` works by itself (assuming Ecto is present as a dependency.)

Comment: If you really do not want to have dependencies, you could just take the parts you need from Ecto's source code.
If all you need is `generate`, it would be a matter of copying the 4 functions at the bottom of this file: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/uuid.ex

Answer (score 15):

If you're using elixir with ecto, you can always use Ecto.UUID https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.UUID.html

Answer (score 9):

The canonical way to generate a globally unique reference in Elixir is with [`make_ref/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.10.4/Kernel.html#make_ref/0).

From the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.10.4/Kernel.html#make_ref/0):

> Returns an almost unique reference.
>
> The returned reference will re-occur after approximately 2^82 calls; therefore it is unique enough for practical purposes.

Comment: I wonder what happens if the OTP restarts.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to include Ecto in your project, you should evaluate https://github.com/zyro/elixir-uuid

```
defp deps do
  [ { :elixir_uuid, "~> 1.2" } ]
end
```

```
iex> UUID.uuid1()
"5976423a-ee35-11e3-8569-14109ff1a304"
```

```
iex> UUID.uuid3(:dns, "my.domain.com")
"03bf0706-b7e9-33b8-aee5-c6142a816478"

iex> UUID.uuid3("5976423a-ee35-11e3-8569-14109ff1a304", "my.domain.com")
"0609d667-944c-3c2d-9d09-18af5c58c8fb"
```

- https://hex.pm/packages/elixir_uuid
- https://github.com/zyro/elixir-uuid
- https://hexdocs.pm/elixir_uuid/readme.html